# Types of property X are incompatible

Tags: typescript, interface

I'm just starting to play around with Typescript and am having what seems to be an odd issue.

I have declared an interface like so:

`Location.d.ts`

```
interface Location {
    lat: number;
    lng: number;
}
```

This interface is then used like this:

`reducer.tsx`

```
interface MapState extends State {
    locations: Location[];
}
```

Now, I am attempting to declare a variable with the type `MapState`, but I'm getting the error:

> Type ... is not assignable to type 'MapState'. Types of property 'locations' are incompatible. Type ... is not assignable to type 'Location[]'. Type ... is not assignable to type 'Location'. Property 'hash' is missing in type ...

Here is my declaration:

```
const initialState: MapState = {
    locations: [
        { lat: 33.488069, lng: -112.072972 }
    ]
};
```

If I explicitly cast the `Location`, then it works:

```
const initialState: MapState = {
    locations: [
        ({ lat: 33.488069, lng: -112.072972 } as Location)
    ]
};
```

But this is terribly verbose. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Property 'hash' is missing in type

This means that `Location` in the place where the error happens is not your `Location` type - it's the type for browser location object defined in [dom.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L9390)

You probably did not import your `Location` type in that file (`reducer.tsx`) or there is some other reason why the compiler does not see it.

Comment: You're correct that I didn't import the type. It is defined in a `.d.ts` file, so I was assuming it was being imported by TS. I was unaware that Location was already a type in TS. Thank you, I will rename the interface to something unique.

Comment: If `Location` is exported in the `.d.ts` file, you have to import it; if it's declared as global type you have to include that `.d.ts` in the compilation somehow, either in `tsconfig.json` or using [`reference` directive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html)

Comment: Also, I really feel like TS should warn me that I'm attempting to overwrite an existing class..

Comment: Well, that warning will conflict with a feature called ["declaration merging"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) which allows you to add properties to a type which is defined elsewhere

Comment: Ahh, that seems kind of like an anti feature when you have inheritance, but thank you for the information. Greatly appreciated!

Comment: One of the language design goals is to allow type-checking of existing javacsript code, so it has to model real-world javascript practice where many people add their own properties to objects they receive from elsewhere without hesitation. TypeScript copes pretty well IMO, you just have to be prepared to deal with errors like that from time to time.